# Using add_theme_page in Wordpress 3.4

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to add a Theme options page, and this is the piece of code i am using..

`add_theme_page('Theme Options', 'Theme Options', 'read', 'theme-option-slug' , 'theme_settings_page');`

I am wondering what does the 'read' in the list of parameters mean. Also, If I replace it with Administrator, it does not work.

What all values Can I use to replace the 'read'. I read on Wordpress CodeX, it is the field for Capability. But, entering options like `Editor`, `Administrator`, etc in the function does not work.

So, I need to know the exact value of the code I can use....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_theme_page) has some useful information on what each parameter is, and how it works. As for the 'read' value, you're pretty close in knowing that it's a type of capability that allows only certain users to see that given page.

Unfortunately, you can't define a Role to determine who can and cannot see your page. You have to define a [Capability](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities). If you only want somebody with administrative privileges to see your page, you need to select a capability that is unique to the Administrator Role.

Change 'read' to something like 'create_users', and that should do what you need. [This Table](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Capability_vs._Role_Table) should help you.

Comment: Sir, I am Very much aware of the Roles and Capabilities... But, I am very confused what to enter in the PHP code, instead of `read`. Because, `read` enables even guest users to access the page.

If you can tell me what I should Write in in the code, I shall be greatful. I need the exact word. Because If you replace it with `Administrator`, `Editor`, the theme options page won't show up.